# Setting Variable values after reading file contents

Tags: coldfusion

I have a very large query which is getting called from 3 different pages.
Instead of writing the same query in all the 3 cfm files, I am trying to find an alternative way to save the query (alongwith #variable(s)#) in a Query.cfm file.

Query.cfm example :

```
SELECT *
    FROM A
    WHERE TRADE_DATE  BETWEEN to_date('#f_startDate#','dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('#f_endDate#','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

variables : #f_startDate# and #f_endDate#

Then I read the filecontents, store it in a variable and replace the #variable(s)# with the values to run the  function from each of the pages.

Calling page (code so far which is not working):

```
<cffile action = "read" file = "#ExpandPath( './Query.cfm')#" variable = "Query">
<cfset Query = #ReplaceList(Query,"#f_startDate#,#f_endDate#", "01/01/2000,01/01/2002")#>   
<cfquery name="Q_DailyPrice" datasource="#f_datasource#">
    #PreserveSingleQuotes(Query)#
</cfquery>
```

How to set the variable values into the string?

Further details about each page:

1. Returns the JSON of the query to load charts
2. Used to generate query data in xls
3. Used further to generate subset of the query data (QoQ) to create a table.

Database : Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options include:

1. Put the query in a .cfm template and access it with cfinclude
2. Put the query into a user defined function in a .cfm file.  Then cfinclude the file and call the function.
3. Put the query into a user defined function in a .cfc file.  Then you can either run the function with cfinvoke, or create an object and then call the function.

There are probably other options as well.  I suggest looking at the three I suggested and determine which one best meets your needs.

Whatever method you use, ColdFusion has a parsedatetime function that will convert your strings to date objects.  Using these might be faster that oracle's to_date function.  You'll have to test and see.  In any event, use cfqueryparameter for a variety of reasons.

Also, be careful about using between with oracle.  Its date fields include a time component.  If any of your records have one, you are safer with

```
where trade_date >= YourStartDate
and trade_date < TheDayAfterYourEndDate
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Even I had been working on using the 1st option of `<cfinclude>` and it WORKED. Furthermore, I had to envelope the query with `<cfoutput>` tags in the Query.cfm file.